# Custom usermeta fields, registration page and login widget wordpress

Tags: wordpress, registration

Here's the situation:
I have an old site, with an old userdatabase (MySQL). I'd like to migrate these users into wordpress without losing the old data (recipe id's, custom user fields etc.).

Besides this i'd like to make a custom registration page with all the (extra) user data i allready had on the old site.

I tried to find some plugins (WP-members, Registration Widget, Register Plus Redux,  etc.), but they all didn't fit my purpose.

I'm starting to think that I probably need to code this myself, but that will make Wordpress unable to update.

Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

Thx, Rick

Comment: Why doesn't Register Plus Redux work for your purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Should be fairly easy although you may have to assign users a new password. That is usually ok with the users as long as they know it's coming.

Take your old database and to a simple sql query to extract the data, then use some code like the following to create a new user for each user in your old database:

```
$newuser = array(
            'user_pass' => wp_generate_password( 12,0 ),
            'user_login' => $email,
            'user_nicename' => $name['first'].' '.$name['last'],
            'user_email' => $email,
            'display_name' => $name['first'].' '.$name['last'],
            'nickname' => $name['first'].' '.$name['last'],
            'first_name' => $name['first'],
            'last_name' => $name['last'],
            //''
        );

        $user_id = wp_insert_user($newuser);
        wp_new_user_notification($user_id, $newuser['user_pass']);
```

This code works as of WordPress 3.1. In this example you'd simply want to replace the $name variables with data that you've provided from your old database.

The last two lines are important because that's where the real work happens. The wp_insert_user function will create the user (or throw an error if you're missing info) and the wp_new_user_notification function will send them an email with their password. I would highly recommend taking the time to rewrite the new user notification plugin (*it's a [pluggable function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API#Pluggable_Functions) so you can just copy paste it to your functions.php and make changes there*) so that the email users get makes sense. You could also write your own email function or if your passwords are stored in plain text simply pass that info on to WP.

**Edit:** I missed your need for custom fields, Gravity Forms does this quite well but you can add a custom field to any user with the [update_user_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta) function. So in the sample code above you'd just want add something after that like:

```
update_user_meta($user_id, "my_custom_data_key", "my_custom_data_value");
```

To retrieve that data for display, you'd just use get_user_meta:

```
print get_user_meta($user_id, "my_custom_data_key");
```

Comment: as long as you add the data to WordPress in this fashion you'll always be able to update.